# Can anyone recommend a great Rig Veda with transliteration?

Tags: rig-veda

Spiritual classics seem to be translated either by scholars or practicing ascetics.

Can anyone recommend a great Rig Veda translated by someone with rich spiritual insight (as opposed to dry scholarly insight), and with a transliteration of the Sanskrit?

Comment: Do you want both translation and transliteration or anyone one of them ok?

Comment: In a book form that u can buy?

Comment: @TheDestroyer translation and transliteration.

Comment: @Rickross that would be good.